# ActionBarSherlock Item Icon strange width with Android 4.3

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I`m developing an App using ActionBarSherlock

One of the items in the menu is a rectangular image. See it`s xml:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/kapturar_action"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/camera_action_icon"
    android:title="@string/kapturar" />
<item
```

So far so good.
The problem is that the SDK 4.3 appears to accept only square images (This is my supposition, i`m not sure of that) and the icon shows in a strange fashion preserving what appears to be a "max width" property.

See the printscreens

Android 2.2 - Simulator:

[image: Android 2.2]

Android 4.1.2 - Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini:

[image: Android 4.1.2]

Android 4.3 - Nexus 4:

[image: Android 4.3]

I double checked the drawables and I think that everything is right.  I have defined the MDPI, HDPI and XHDPI images.

Can anybody affirm that is impossible to use rectangular drawables in the menu`s item? Is there a way to fix the problem in the Android 4.3 preserving the backward-compatible?

Comment: Check again the drawable and, before install it again, clean and rebuild your project

Comment: Did that again and nothing. :(

Comment: what about a workaround: make a layout that looks like you want it and add it programmatically to `ActionBar`?

Comment: because it is a button, not only a view.

Comment: Have you tried ActionBar Compat?

Comment: what is ActionBar Compat?

Comment: ActionBarCompat is the Google analog of ActionBarSherlock. It is official but not open source.

Comment: Since when did the actionbar support not squared icons ? I think you'll need to remove the shape around your button and use the default behavior, which is an icon with an all caps text with the default font.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Action Bar Sherlock is now [deprecated](https://plus.google.com/+JakeWharton/posts/F3HkWY9J8fK) as Google released their own [Action Bar compatibility library](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2013/08/actionbarcompat-and-io-2013-app-source.html).

I strongly recommend to switch to that official library, I guess/hope your problem won't appear there.

Comment: Yep, Jake Wharton stated that will stop with future development of ABS.

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski can you, please, point where Jake stated that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use compatibility version of ActionBar. This is not very good answer but it will help you.

To make it just comment line

```
registerImplementation(ActionBarSherlockNative.class);
```

In ActionBarSherlock class.

Moreover after this you can edit sources, resources in ActionBarSherlock and they will look the same on Android 2.3 and Android 4.0+ devices.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your drawable into another folder. I mean if it is in drawable-xhdpi folder put it to drawable-hdpi (or other).
Sometimes it solves the problem with resizing images from resources